# Происхождение выражения "в три погибели"

Tags: фразеология

Согнуться в три погибели — значит, согнуться очень низко, наклониться. А почему так говорят "в три погибели"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Слово ПОГИБЕЛЬ имеет тот же корень, что и слово ГИБНУТЬ. Др.-рус. **гыбнути** восходит к праслав. глаголу *gybnọti, который выражал знач. «гибнуть» и **«гнуть»**. Первонач., надо полагать, было «гнуть». Логично предположить, что "в три погибели" означает буквально - 'трижды согнув(шись)', 'в три сложения'.